# Mapping all tables on SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

A dumb question but I couldn't get why it does not work.
I have a DB with several tables. I can map it manually

```
Earnings = Table ('Earnings', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

or automatically using a loop.

```
tablenames = inspect(engine).get_table_names()
for tabname in tablenames:
    tabname = Table (tabname, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

I can use this code to see the mapped tables :

```
for tab in metadata.tables:
    print (tab)
...
>>> Earnings
...
```

So far, no problem.

The question is that if try use the automatically mapped tables, it does not locate it.

```
Lista_colunas = Earnings.columns.items()
for col in Lista_colunas:
    print (col)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\fabio\Banco do Brasil S.A\DINED Parcerias Digitais - General\Python\Amazon\SQLA_Access_Test.ipynb Cell 13' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Lista_colunas = Earnings.columns.items()
      2 for col in Lista_colunas:
      3     print (col)

NameError: name 'Earnings' is not defined
```

I realized that the auto mode is not creating the variables with the 'tabnames', but why not?

Somehow, VSCODE identifies that the 'Earnings' is a table objetc (see the picture), but does not let me call for it.

[image: VScode mouseover]

Answer (score 2):

Once the loop has completed, `tabname` will always be the table that corresponds to the final entry tin `tablenames`.  You could collect the tables in a `dict` keyed on `tabname`, but SQLAlchemy already provides a way to do this:

```py
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)  # Reflect all tables in the database.
Earnings = metadata.tables['Earnings']
```

The docs for reflection in general are [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#), the docs for `MetaData.reflect` are [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect).

Comment: Ok. The variable 'tabname' will have the last table nome. No issue here.

I am listing the existinting tables by doing this and it shows me a list of tables.
'for tab in metadata.tables:
    print(tab)'

Even when I type the name 'Earnings", VSCODE shows it a Table object "(Variable) Earnings : Table"

Comment: By doing your suggestion, how do I do a loop to create variables for all tables?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to create variables, since you can access them via the metadata object's `tables` attribute.  But some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/5320906) might help you.  I don't use VSCode so I can't explain its behaviour.

Comment: Variables just to be quick and easier to access such tables. Like it would work on a manual mapping.  It's easier to say earnings.c.revebue than Metadata.tables[earnjngs].c.revenue